# Mansplaining: Is the word itself acceptable in the workplace?

Tags: work-environment, ethics, gender, language

I can only find information from Google about the *act* of mansplaining within the workplace.

I'm curious about usage of the word itself within the workplace.

Is the word itself frowned upon in any context, or is it acceptable in all contexts?

Location is the US. Industry shouldn't matter.

Comment: There is no global "workplace" in which this question can be answered. At the very least, please add your location and industry.

Comment: Added location. Industry shouldn't matter.

Comment: Industry absolutely matters: what is accepted in a blue collar mining job in the Rust Belt is going to be very, _very_ different from what is accepted in trendy startup in Silicon Valley.

Comment: Ok, it's an office job mainly filled with electrical, mechanical, and software engineers. However, it seems that things like gender bias, hostile work environments, etc., should be treated the same no matter the industry. I'd love to hear examples.

Comment: Maybe it should. But this is a site for asking questions about actual practical problems in the workplace, not theoretical debates, so questions need to be reasonably scoped.

Answer (score 6):

Mansplaining is an insult to all men.  Whether it is acceptable to use a term that is an insult to all men will depend upon the industry and context.

For instance, just about anything goes in the entertainment industry because you can’t represent bad people without showing how they are bad.

It will also depend upon who is using the term and how, if it is a man asking “am I mansplaining?” it might be mildly acceptable.  If it is in regards to using a google ngram on insulting words, it would be 100% acceptable.

Comment: Not all men "mansplain" and not all "mansplaining" is done by men.  That's what makes it not only insulting but paints the person saying it as ignorant.

Comment: How is the term mansplaining an insult to all men?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that one should be quite careful saying this to someone's face in a workplace setting. When you (as a woman) thinks a man explains something in a condescending way to you and/or explains something you know more about than you, just ask him to change his tone or ask him to stop talking about this particular point/issue. I think mansplaining in a worksetting is quite a stronge word. Good luck next time getting some necessary information from someone you called a mansplainer about something he actually does know more about than you.